# A homework about continuity and limit

Tags: limits, continuity

I really don't know how to make a good title for a homework question.

My problem is problem 29, section 1.1, chapter 1 of [Burden & Faires' Numerical Analysis (9th)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0059JHM6M). This is [a working PDF copy](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/numerical_analysis_9th.pdf).

> Let $ f \in C [a, b]$, $ p \in (a, b) $ and $ f(p) \neq 0 $.
>
> Show that a $ \delta > 0 $ exist with $ f(x) \neq 0 \, \forall x \in [p - \delta, p + \delta]$, with $ [p - \delta, p + \delta] \subset [a, b] $.

I have the solution manual for the 8th edition, which is as follow:

> $ f $ is continuous at $ p $, and $ f(p) \neq 0 $, there exist $ \delta > 0 $ with:
>
> $$ |f(x) - f(p)| < \dfrac{|f(p)|}{2} \tag{1}\label{1} $$
>
> for $ |x - p| < \delta $ and $ a < x < b $. We *restrict* $ \delta $ so that $ [p - \delta, p + \delta] \subset [a, b] $.

I'm struggling to understand the *restrict* part and the inequation $ \ref{1} $.

1. I thought that we have to prove

   > There exist $ \delta $ such that it satisfies:
   >
   > 1. $ [p - \delta, p + \delta] \subset [a, b] $, and
   > 2. $ f(x) \neq 0 \, \forall x \in [p - \delta, p + \delta]$

   How can the solution outright declare that 1. is true?
2. How can I come up with $ \dfrac{f(p)}{2} $?

   I understand that they're using the definition of limit (given in the book):

   > A function has the limit $ L $ at $ x_0 $ if, given any $ \varepsilon > 0 $,
   > there exists a real $ \delta > 0 $ such that:
   >
   > $$ |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon \, \forall x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) $$

   But why do they choose $ \varepsilon = \dfrac{|f(p)|}{2}$? From the rest of the solution, I think any $ \varepsilon < |f(p)| $ will do it. This is the rest:

   > $$ f(p) - \varepsilon < f(x) < f(p) + \varepsilon $$
   >
   > 1. If $ f(p) < 0 $, then $ f(x) < f(p) + |f(p)| = 0 $
   > 2. If $ f(p) > 0 $, then $ f(x) > f(p) - |f(p)| = 0 $
   >
   > In both cases, $ f(x) \neq 0 \, \forall x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) $

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @MinhNghia Regarding 1. maybe they could have used $\delta_1$ and $\delta$... First they establish that for $|x-p| < \delta_1$ everything goes well and then they just say that they will pick $\delta < \delta_1$ so that $[p-\delta, p+\delta]\subset [a,b]$.

Comment: @PierreCarre So that `with... with` statement doesn't mean that the $ \delta $ have to satisfy both? So what is the use of the $ [p - \delta, p + \delta] \subset [a, b] $ part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to prove that $[p-\delta,p+\delta]\subset [a,b]$ since there are only two options:

(1) $[p-\delta,p+\delta]\subset [a,b]$, then we are done.

(2) $[p-\delta,p+\delta]$ is not in $[a,b]$. Then, since the property holds for every $x\in[p-\delta,p+\delta]$, it certainly holds for any $x\in [p-\delta_{1},p+\delta_{1}]$ where $0<\delta_{1}<\delta$. Choosing $\delta_{1}$ so that $[p-\delta_{1},p+\delta_{1}]$ belongs to $[a,b]$ makes the statement  true.

(An explicit choice of this $\delta_{1}$, in case $[p-\delta,p+\delta]$ is not in $[a,b]$, is $\delta_{1}=\min\{\frac{b-p}{2},\frac{p-a}{2}\}$).

---

$\dfrac{|f(p)|}{2}$ is half the distance between $f(p)$ and $0$. It is a good trick to get a measure of distance which is between two objects that is *lesser* than the exact distance between them. You can pick any $\varepsilon<|f(p)|$ as you say, but it is "unnecessarily" precise.

By unnecessary I mean something like:

Suppose we wish to prove that you and I are not the same person, we both know it since we (for sake of argument) are 500 meters apart: So I say that "Because there is at least 250 meters between us therefore we are not the same person". You say "We are 0.0000000001 millimeters apart therefore we are not the same person".

We are both correct, but in this argument, just like in the question, it is only important that *there exists a non-zero distance* between us ($f(p)$ and $0$ in the question) and not what minimal distance needs to exist to make this true.